# Close Marionette nested regions

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

If I close a region, that has also a nested region - will it properly close the both or every region should be closed separately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every child of a region that is being closed will also be closed properly. So there's no need to do that separately.

See: https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.layout.md#closing-a-layout

Comment: Thanks! I somehow missed it in the doc